# Why adding value to a long variable makes it lower?

Tags: java, android, long-integer

I am trying to add 30 days to `System.long a = System.currentTimeMillis() + ((long)30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);` but it is deceasing the value? Why? This is what i have tried

```
int days = 30;
long a = System.currentTimeMillis();
long b = a + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
```

According to the time I run the code, it was the result:

a = `1646737213282` , b = `1645034245986`

Why `b` < `a` ?

Comment: try to print `(days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)` - that is an `int` operation since all operands are `int` - it will overflow and become negative (`-1702967296`) || solution: declare `days` as `long` or use cast `((long) day * 24 * ...)` {or just add an L to 24 `(day * 24L * ...)` not so easy to spot})

Comment: The `(days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)` computation is done using 32 bit (`int`) arithmetic, and it probably overflows.  Change it to `((long) days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)` or declare `days` as `long`.

Comment: change `days` to `long`, in order to perform long multiplications.

Comment: as @user16320675 and others mentioned, days should be long too :-\
It could be an exam question :))))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the int range is being exceeded. The max int range is from

`-2,147,483,648 (-231) to 2,147,483,647 (231-1)`

When you multiply, it is stored as a `int`. But, that's not the limit. So, the solution will be to parse it to a long. You can check out my code below:

```java
int days = 30;
long a = System.currentTimeMillis();
long b = a + ((long)days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
System.out.println("a = " + a + "       b = " + b);
```

But if you want to optimise the code, this code will be better:

```
long a = System.currentTimeMillis() + ((long)30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
System.out.println("a = " + a);
```

It saves your 2 lines of code

But, I'd also prefer you to use a method

```
long addDays(int days){
    return System.currentTimeMillis() + ((long)days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
}
```

and then

```
int a = addDays(30);
```